# jQuery buscar todos os checkboxes checked de uma div através de um clique em botão

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Preciso buscar todos os ***checkboxes*** ***CHECKED*** de uma `<div>` na qual possui uma outra `<div>` filha que esta, possue um `<input type="checkbox">` via 
`jQuery`.

Segue a estrutura:

```
<div class="metro perfil-filtro-expander-filtrados perfil-filtro-expander-overflow acoesFiltradas" id="acoesFiltradas">
     <--! item 1 -->
     <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
          <input id="@item.SelectedValue" type="checkbox" />
          <label for="@item.SelectedValue">
          <b>@item.Title</b>
          <br />
          <span class="perfil-filtro-expander-descricao">
               @item.Description
          </span>
          </label>
    </div>
    <--! item 2 -->
    <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
         <input id="@item.SelectedValue" type="checkbox" />
         <label for="@item.SelectedValue">
         <b>@item.Title</b>
         <br />
         <span class="perfil-filtro-expander-descricao">
              @item.Description
         </span>
         </label>
    </div>
    <--! item 3 -->
    <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
         <input id="@item.SelectedValue" type="checkbox" />
         <label for="@item.SelectedValue">
         <b>@item.Title</b>
         <br />
         <span class="perfil-filtro-expander-descricao">
               @item.Description
         </span>
         </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#copiarParaTodasAcoes").click(function () {
    $(".acoesFiltradas :input:checked").each(function () {
        alert('teste');
    });
});
```

Botão:

```
<a href="">
   <img class="perfil-expander-botoes" id="copiarParaTodasAcoes" src="~/Images/tecbox/icons/expander-copy-icon.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: O erro esta no jeito que você esta chamando no jQuery `$(".acoesFiltradas :input:checked")` mude para `$(".acoesFiltradas input:checked")`

Comment: nenhum feedback.. o alerta não é exibido ainda.

Comment: Não prestei atenção em todo o código, analisando melhor, verifiquei que o erro esta no seu botão, a imagem esta dentro de um link que esta com o link para a mesma página `<a href="">`, ele tenta chamar o javascript, porém a página já é redireciona no mesmo momento. link do seu código funcionando https://jsfiddle.net/dbk7a1os/, mudei o javascript e html do botão.

Comment: não esta funcionando aqui, não sei por que motivos... Por favor, insira o código baseado na minha pergunta como resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode alterar o seu código do botão e javascript por esses:

**Botão** (a mudança esta em por o id na tag do link `<a>` e remover da imagem)

```
<a href="" id="copiarParaTodasAcoes">
   <img class="perfil-expander-botoes" src="~/Images/tecbox/icons/expander-copy-icon.png" />
</a>
```

**Javascript:** (adicionado o `preventDefault()` para que ignore a ação principal do link e removi os ':' do seletor do input)

```
$("#copiarParaTodasAcoes").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".acoesFiltradas input:checked").each(function () {
        alert('teste');
    });
});
```

O restante do html continua o mesmo. [link do exemplo funcionando](https://jsfiddle.net/yp0vmybs/)

Obs.: Testei no Firefox e Chorme.

Comment: Sem resposta ainda... não sei por que motivos... acho que é por que estou estilizando o checkbox como o da seguinte forma: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80628/checkbox-style-com-estilo-metro verifique se isso pode afetar, por favor... verifique que o checkbox não alterna para true ou false o checked. Engraçado que nos testes aqui eu ponho um alert na primeira linha na function e ele não é mais exibido também.

Comment: Apresenta algum erro no console do browser? se puder passar alguma url de homologação para darmos uma olhada

Comment: pior que não apresenta nada... sem feedback algum! E também não possuo a Url... se você entrar no link em que falei, verá as classes que editam o meu checkbox através da div com classe 'metro'.

Comment: É alguma coisa que esta dando conflito, joguei os css do link que você passou e funcionou certinho (apenas o primeiro item é selecionado pelo fato deles possuírem o mesmo id) - [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/yp0vmybs/1/)

Comment: verdade, vou ter que descobrir!

Comment: Se você não conseguir, tenta subir em algum ambiente que tento ajudar.

Comment: Caramba! Era o cash do browser que não estava trocando a versão salva. Executei no modo anônimo e foi de primeira! Valeu!!!

Comment: como faço o mesmo mas para apenas os não checados?

Comment: Você pode usar o seletor `:not()`, ficaria assim `$(".acoesFiltradas input:not(:checked)")`

Comment: Perfeito! Valeu a ajuda.

Comment: Agora dentro da lista, como eu acesso as propriedades de cada div? Na verdade não postei aqui, mas o que eu fiz, foi um .each dentro de outro para fazer algumas comparações, e então preciso acessar os dados de cada objeto destes "each's", sei que através do "this", consigo pegar o do each atual, porém preciso comparar com o outro each.

Answer (score 1):

Retirar o elemento `<a>` que está encapsulando o elemento `<img>`, pois este não possui propósito.
A menos que você prefira retirar o elemento `<img>` e passar o src da imagem como background do elemento `<a>`. Neste caso será necessario utilizar o seguinte script: `e.preventDefault();`

```
$("#copiarParaTodasAcoes").on('click', function (e) {
    // caso seja utilizada a tag <a>: e.preventDefault();

    // o filtro para selecionar os inputs 'checked'
    // pode ser feito com o 'find' do jquery
    // $('.acoesFiltradas').find('input:checked')

    $(".acoesFiltradas input:checked").each(function () {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: não obtive resposta também, por favor, leia meu comentário que esta na resposta do Jeferson.